Unable to select object at the beginning, so have load factory setting all the time
I am unable to select object at the beginning, so I have load factory setting all the time.
Here I attached my loading screen.https://youtu.be/4ICLWBlc-JE
Also I can't select Scene Collection at this point.
I tried uninstall- and reinstalled several times, deleted the remaining blender folder.
Also I installed the newest Blenderversion 4.1, and had the same problem.

Ok....I figured it out. Delete this folder and restart your Blender will help. C:\Users\MY_PC\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation
